# Pandas - Faster way to find same value in different columns in CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to find rows that have circular referenced in the CSV input file like:

```
start,end,weather
california,arizona,hot
colorado,kansas,cold
arizona,california,hot
```

The above should detect that the 1st and 3rd row a circular reference. I'm currently loading the csv into database and running a self-join query to determine that the data has circular reference. But looking to see if there is any way to handle this using Python Pandas.

Thanks!

Comment: How about `california -> arizona`, `arizona -> kansas`, `kansas -> california`? Do you need to handle this loop?

Comment: No, only the first level circular reference and not transitive loop. Thanks!

Comment: Does `right` / `left` matter? What if the last row has `right` relation?

Comment: yes, it needs to be the same relation. Updated the sample in the question posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the rows where the value of df.start Serie is contain in the df.end Serie. Then you appy a second filter to get the rows where the value of df.end Serie is contain in the df.start Serie :

```
df = df.loc[df.start.isin(df.end),:]
df = df.loc[df.end.isin(df.start),:]
df["way"] = df.apply(lambda x: sorted([x["start"], x["end"]]), axis=1)
print(df)
```

The output will give you line 0 and 2.

Comment: Is there anyway to ensure the 3rd column is the same?

Comment: I updated my answer by adding a new Series that does the job